# Jquery, mootools and prototype in Joomla

Tags: javascript, mootools, prototypejs, javascript-framework, conflict

Hi I need Mootools for my chronoforms, prototype for my lightbox 2 (I think) and maybe also some jQuery in the future.
When I enable Mootools, lightbox 2 is not working in IE, when I disable it, lightbox works fine but I get errors on my page from my chronoforms form.

Is there a good and easy way to make sure you don't get any problems using all three together?

And something like `JQuery.noConflict()` is not an easy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have MooTools and Prototype co-exist.

This is because they both change (extend) native host objects (Types) like `Element` (MooTools) and `Array`, `Function`, `String`, `Number` (both). You can't `noConflict` this for the life of you, each method can be defined once.

It's going to be pot luck when you reference `"foo".contains('oo')` and it goes to `String.prototype.contains` (for instance) if you get Prototype's, Mootools or ES5's implementations (MooTools 1.5.1+).

Time to reconsider what you use as you really should go to a single framework - they all can do what you need individually.

You can also have MooTools + jQuery or Prototype + jQuery, however

Comment: Thanks, so I better download slimbox 2 and use it togheter with mootools (a lot of joomla plugins use it). How do I use the noconflict, do I have to change every $ to JQuery?

Comment: depends on your version of mootools. if you are on mootools 1.2.3+ then it's simple. just load jquery before you load mootools and mootools will drop to using `document.id()` instead of $. if you are on older mootools, then you need the `noConflict` and you need to load jquery afterwards. changing $ to jQuery will work or use a closure like `(function($) { console.log($); // jQuery })(jQuery);` around your code - keeping $ assigned to what it should be within the function. just careful about scope management. the reverse applies if mootools goes to document.id - just pass document.id above.

Comment: thanks man, it works without changing anything so jquery is probably loaded before mootools.